# unusable-partial-specialization error with Clang by default

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, clang++

I am just programming with C++ templates, but Clang gave me an error by default.

The code below:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <int... vals>
struct int_seq {};

template <typename>
struct pop_back;

template <int... vals, int val>
struct pop_back<int_seq<vals..., val>>
    : std::enable_if<true, std::pair<std::integral_constant<int, val>, int_seq<vals...>>> {};
```

Can be compiled successfully with GCC and MSVC. But Clang will give an `-Wunusable-partial-specialization` error:

```bash
$ clang++ -std=c++17 -c main.cpp
error: class template partial specialization contains template parameters that cannot be deduced; this partial specialization will never be used [-Wunusable-partial-specialization]
```

However, if we specify the `-Wno-unusable-partial-specialization` option, it can be compiled successfully:

```bash
$ clang++ -std=c++17 -c main.cpp -Wno-unusable-partial-specialization
```

Diff view in godbolt:
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/sd6MW5MTT

So which behavior is correct?

Comment: Does it do "the right thing" when you compile it with `-Wno-unusable-partial-specialization`? Can you add a usage example to the question too?

Comment: Looks like IFNDR as you're not using the template. Once you use it, it will become ill-formed.

Answer (score 2):

> So which behavior is correct?

The program is **ill-formed** as per [temp.class.spec.match#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.class.spec.match#3) as the template parameter cannot be deduced:

> **If the template arguments of a partial specialization cannot be deduced because of the structure of its template-parameter-list and the template-id, the program is ill-formed.**
>
> [Example 3 :
>
> ```
> template <int I, int J> struct A {};
> template <int I> struct A<I+5, I*2> {}; // error
> ```
>
> end example]

(emphasis mine)

---

Note that if you don't actually use the template then the program is ill-formed no diagnostic required. But once you start using it, it will be ill-formed and a diagnostic should be issued in that case. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/Ese4vddEn) is a demo that actually uses the template and makes the program ill-formed.